# Android studio getting "UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libhoudini.so" not found" while trying to run my first NDK app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

Thanks in advance, I am new for NDK development, and i am trying to run my first app of it just want to print "Hello world" from Android studio.

Below is the exception that i am getting

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library
>   "/system/lib/libhoudini.so" not found
>               at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:333)
>               at java.lang.System.load(System.java:512)
>               at com.tutorial.s.myapplications.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:17)
>               at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Below is the buil.gradle file of app

apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

> model {
>       android {
>           compileSdkVersion = 23
>           buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
>
> ```
>     defaultConfig.with {
>         applicationId = "com.tutorial.s.myapplications"
>         minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 16
>         targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
>     }
> }
> android.ndk {
>     moduleName = "mainactivity"
> }
> android.buildTypes {
>     release {
>         minifyEnabled = false
>         proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
>     }
> } } dependencies {
> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
> testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' }
> ```

Please let me know if you need any more detail for helping me out of it.

Comment: on what device/emulator you are running this?

Comment: I have tried it on Lenovo K3 note and genymotion(emulator)

Comment: and this error show up also on that lenovo? because for genymotion is normal to see that

Comment: if you are using google sample like this one: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-jni/app/build.gradle for genymotion builds you need to select x86 flavor. The difference is that genymotion emulator runs on x86 architecture and does not come with capability of running arm code.

Comment: @V-master you are right it is normal to see this bug on Genymotion. But ya i have tried it on Lenovo also even now i have also tried it on Nexus 5X